# string trimmer slits bottom screen door

Tags: repair, screens

I live in a condo with a back doorwall, but no patio. The doorwall opens directly onto lawn.
In summer, the grounds crew comes through with a weed trimmer and (since no patio) trims right up the to house.
In doing so, they repeatedly cut a slit in the bottom of the screen door, allowing bugs and dirt to enter the house. I've repaired the screen twice, but they just cut through again.
Short of installing a patio that I probably won't use very much, is there any cheap way to fix/prevent this problem?
I've googled for this problem, but it returns no references at all. I find it hard to believe that I have encountered something completely unique.

Comment: Add a couple of rows of pavers in front of the door? Take a 4" x 4' strip of hardware cloth, trim so the wires stick out of all four edges, bend wires 90°, push through bottom of screen from the outside, and then fold the wires all the way to hold the screen in place?

Comment: Make them pay for the damaged screen? After a couple of times they might remember to stop doing it.

Answer (score 5):

I solved a similar problem (cat scratching a low screen) by attaching a piece of clear acrylic plastic to the frame, just high enough to prevent damage, and still allowing ventilation through the upper part of the screen. I would guess 8 - 10 inches across the bottom would be sufficient to guard against string trimmers.

My frame was wood, so drilling some holes for screws was easy. Might be harder if you have aluminum. Also, the cut edge of the acrylic was not especially nice looking.

Answer (score 0):

You could get a new door?

[image]

... but seriously, I think sending them the invoice for the repair is the more appropriate action.

Answer (score 0):

A steel pet protector should be sufficient.  I would personally add a little edge to it to trim the weedeater lines if they get too close.

Answer (score -1):

1/8" or 1/4" hardware cloth (galvanized or stainless steel mesh, which a string trimmer can't cut - also a stock pet protection measure) over the screen.  Rather than the "poke through the edges of the screen" method suggested in the first comment, this is normally screwed right to the face of the door, with some trim, 12-18" high (or the bottom screen panel, depending on door design.)

But billing them for the negligent damages is still the correct thing.